# How to select a row in laravel using title not the Id line ::find(); method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I trying to find a row using the title, I need just one record
I need a query like `$art = Artists::find($id);` but I don't want to use Id I want to find that by title

```
public function getArtist($slug){
    //$art = Artists::where('slug', $slug)->take(1)->get();
    $art = Artists::find(1);
    return $art;
}
```

I need to show the result like this:

```
{
"id": 1,
"title": "yaghoub-emdadian",
"brithday": null,
"thumbnail": "storage/upload/artists/cover/4_1578739156.jpg",
"created_at": "2020-01-11 10:13:46",
"updated_at": "2020-01-11 10:39:18"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you could use [where()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#where-clauses) and [first()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#retrieving-results):

```
Artist::where('title', $title)->first();
```

Comment: @amirhossein Glad I could help!

Comment: I don't know how to do that